# URL with WWW before it works only on first load Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, service-worker, elastic-load-balancer

I ran into an interesting problem today. When accessing my site https://justbookr.com/ with a `www` in front of the URL in an incognito window in Chrome, the site opens correctly. But after a few refreshes, Chrome throws an error - `The web page at https://www.justbookr.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.`.

I am running on Elastic Beanstalk behind a load balancer, and have not set up anything in the deployment config of Beanstalk to handle redirections or anything with `www`. I have a CNAME record for www.justbookr.com with the value of justbookr.com.

I'm just curious as to why it would work on initial load, and then fail after a refresh? Accessing the site without `www` works fine all the time.

Why would this happen?

EDIT: I also have a Service Worker --- do I need to set `www` as well in the Worker?

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(/https:\/\/justbookr.com/, workbox.strategies.networkFirst({ cacheName: "JustBookr-production", plugins: [] }), 'GET');

workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute('/https:\/\/justbookr.com/');
```

Comment: Check the browser gets, it seems somewhere in your setup or the app on refresh the url is being re-written to http://www.justbookr.com/https://justbookr.com

Comment: Ooo interesting - how'd you see this? What was the steps you took? I didn't run into this...

Comment: I also see this error in the chrome dev tools console :  Fetch API cannot load https://www.justbookr.com/https://justbookr.com/. Redirect failed. (after refreshing)

Comment: Just do a F12 in Chrome and look at the network tab.

Comment: Wow I must be so tired - that was a pretty obvious debugging step :P. It looks like the error is caused by the service worker...